# Problems with auto layout in iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, autolayout

It's been a while since I have built a app for iOS and I am running in to issue with auto layout. I have been trying to add a small subview in and a text field but on the iPhone 5 they lineup properly, but on the iphone 6 the view is a lot bigger than I would expect it to be. The size or ratio just doesn't match what is on the iPhone 5.

You can see with these examples of what I expect and what I am actually getting on the 6.

[image: First subview constraints]
[image: Second subview constraints]
[image: What it ends up look like on the 6]

A similar issue is happening with the text fields. On the 5 it's in the right spot, but on the 6 i can't get it to show up in the same spot.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's impossible to say what you're doing wrong without knowing what you're doing in the first place. How are you adding these views and what constraints are you using?

Comment: Does that give you layout warnings in the console? If you're pinning to the top and the bottom and also setting an aspect ratio those things will come into conflict on different sized screens

Comment: Inside my main view controller I have added a subview with set to be 20 from the left, top, and bottom, removed constrain to margin and set it to aspect ratio. The size of that view is adjusting properly. When I add a textfield to it and give it some constraints for it to potentially be the in the exact spot not matter what device. I essentially center it and give it a top spacing.

Comment: But on the 5 its the right distance from the top and on the 6 it's 20% closer to the top. I tried adding a subview for the textfields to see if I could get it to work with that using similar constraints, but what it ends up doing is making the subview something like 3x as large on the 6.

Comment: And yes I am getting some warning. I need to look closer at them. I have tried a lot of combinations to get it to work properly.

Comment: It's pretty hard to follow what you want from those diagrams in your question and the description in your comments. I'd suggest some actual screenshots of your app, and some from the storyboard showing the constraints in use. And include the constraint warnings from the logs.

Comment: There is an edit button to update your question rather than put loads of stuff in comments.

Comment: I added some screenshots. Hopefully that helps. At the moment I am not getting an errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing and matching aspect ratios and hardcoded distance numbers.

- The red view is going to be a fixed distance from the top, left and bottom of the superview, with a set aspect ratio
- The red view will therefore be bigger on a larger screen, but with the same proportions
- The white view is a fixed distance from the top, left, bottom and right edges of the red view
- The white view will therefore be different sizes on larger screens, but not necessarily in proportion, because the distances you are insetting the view don't change

If you want the whole thing to scale proportionally (which seems odd for a text field, which you'd expect to be the same height everywhere then you'd need to do something like pin the white view to the left, bottom and right of the superview and give it an aspect ratio constraint.

Don't forget there are also specific height or width constraints you can add to views as well - you don't have to determine everything relative to the superview.

The orange lines in the editor are telling you that the frames you're seeing don't currently match up to the constraints you have chosen for the views. You should choose "Update frames" from the resolve issues menu to give you a better picture of what you're looking at. The layout preview assistant will also be very useful for checking how your layout looks in multiple screen sizes simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am trying to get my head around the auto layouts. That seems to be helping a lot.